# Fetching the list of Markers from Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have loaded a geoJson data into a google Map based off the following Google Map Example

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-simple

How do I get the list of Markers as a list using Google API.

Managed to find something at

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data

forEach(callback:function(Data.Feature))

Answer (score 0):

Did you opened the json source file? https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json

You will find latlng values at 'coordinates' properties.